# Как в Android Studio добавить полосу ограничения длины строки справа?

Tags: android, android-studio

Почему-то перестала отображаться полоса показывающая ограничение длины строки в Android Studio. Как ее включить в настройках?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Settings -> Editor -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap guide

Это основной параметр, настраивается он в Code Style options

Comment: простите, это что-то типа красной строки в школе?

Comment: хахахах, очень прикольное сравнение). На самом деле это очень важная вещь, которая со временем изменилась из-за изменения размеров экрана, описывается во многих книгах по CodeStyle и сильно влияет на читаемость. От этого будет зависеть автокоррекция строк типо cntrl + alt + L и сейчас очень многие придерживаются inLine style. Так что в больших компаниях в CodeStyle, четко прописывают кол-во символов в 1 линии. Да и это как поля в тетради, вроде можно зайти, но lead-у это не понравится.

Comment: вот теперь все ясно. спасибо)